Rollback pg_restore result
Maybe somebody can help me with the issue regarding pg-restore. I have restored database from pg_dump with the command below
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_restore --host=host --username=username --dbname=dbname --port=6432 --format=d --verbose pg_backup --single-transaction --no-privileges

The issue is that I did it from user account, not from system user. I would like to know if there is a command to rollback pg_restore result so I can do it once again from another user.
Thanks in advance!

That command is called DROP DATABASE.

You are aware that PostgreSQL version 10 is EOL for some years?
